# overlap between found contours

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using EMGU wrapper.
I  split image to contours:

```
  Contour<Point> contours = img.FindContours();
```

Is there any way to know whether the overlap between found contours.

Answer (score 0):

For ignoring overlapped contour(contour inside contour) you should use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL as contour retrieval mode in findContours() function, which retrieves only the extreme outer contours. See OpenCV [Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First you are misusing the findcontours function.
this is the right method :
FindContours(image, contours, her, RetrType, ChainApproxMethod);

When you successfully figure out the right method for finding the contours you can check 
IntersectsWith() function to find overlaping contours.